Flutter ARCore Plugin keeps crashing
I am currently developing a form of augmented image recognition app for a project and for some reason, my AR page only works upon one visit. What I mean by that is:
I open the AR page, scan the image, get results, exit the AR Page, enter the AR page, and Crash.
From what I gathered, there are some exception handling issues, but I am not too sure.
Here's the code if anyone would like to have a look and help out.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:arcore_flutter_plugin/arcore_flutter_plugin.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:shopping_mall_app/app/pages/main_menu.dart';

class ARScan extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ARScan createState() => _ARScan();
}

class _ARScan extends State<ARScan> {
  ArCoreController? arCoreController;
  Map<int, ArCoreAugmentedImage> augmentedImagesMap = {};
  bool showOverlay = false;
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> productList = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('AugmentedPage'),
          leading: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MainMenu()),
                    (route) => false,
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
        body: Stack(
          children: [
            ArCoreView(
              onArCoreViewCreated: _onArCoreViewCreated,
              type: ArCoreViewType.AUGMENTEDIMAGES,
            ),
            if (showOverlay) _buildOverlay(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildOverlay() {
    return Positioned(
      bottom: 20,
      left: 20,
      right: 20,
      child: Material(
        color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.8),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    'Detected Deals!',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                  IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.close),
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        showOverlay = false;
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 10),
              ...productList.map((product) => ListTile(
                leading: product['ImageURL'] != null
                    ? Image.network(product['ImageURL'], width: 50)
                    : Icon(Icons.image),
                title: Text(product['Product Name'] ?? 'Unnamed Product'),
                subtitle: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Text('Cost: ${product['Enter Product Cost'] ?? 'N/A'}'),
                    Text('Discount: ${product['Enter Discount'] ?? 'N/A'}'),
                    Text('Points: ${product['Enter Points'] ?? 'N/A'}'),
                  ],
                ),
              )),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _onArCoreViewCreated(ArCoreController controller) async {
    arCoreController = controller;
    arCoreController?.onTrackingImage = _handleOnTrackingImage;
    loadSingleImage();
    fetchProductsFromFirebase();
  }

  loadSingleImage() async {
    final ByteData bytes = await rootBundle.load('Assets/testings.jpg');
    arCoreController?.loadSingleAugmentedImage(
      bytes: bytes.buffer.asUint8List(),
    );
  }

  fetchProductsFromFirebase() async {
    final querySnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .doc('7r6AWJR9HlaHZQ05GE4bmKtkjE13')
        .collection('products')
        .get();

    setState(() {
      productList = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()).toList();
    });
  }

  _handleOnTrackingImage(ArCoreAugmentedImage augmentedImage) {
    if (!augmentedImagesMap.containsKey(augmentedImage.index)) {
      augmentedImagesMap[augmentedImage.index] = augmentedImage;
    }
      setState(() {
        showOverlay = true;
      });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    arCoreController?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}


There is also an issue of the overlay not disappearing once I tap on the X icon. I'm not sure why that is happening, either. Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!
I've tried various methods of trying to dispose of the page, but it always comes back as an error exception in the logs.
These are the logs:

W/ArSceneView( 7710): The session has already been setup, cannot set
it up again. I/ViewRootImpl@e3c0764MainActivity:
onDisplayChanged oldDisplayState=2 newDisplayState=2 I/Choreographer(
7710): Skipped 1433 frames!  The application may be doing too much
work on its main thread. I/native  ( 7710): I0000
00:00:1731942793.105681    7710 pursuit_tracker.cc:1518]
AugmentedRegion config changed, enabled:1, quad:true, downsample:true,
global reacquisition:false, lite mode:false, adaptive frame
delay:false, interpolation:true, feature match stats:false, sharpness
score computation:false,
enable_pursuit_higher_frequent_reacquisition_on_roi:false,
enable_profiling:false W/native  ( 7710): W0000
00:00:1731942793.108328    8666 motion_analysis_calculator.cc:387] No
input video header found. Downstream calculators expecting video
headers are likely to fail. I/native  ( 7710): I0000
00:00:1731942793.114430    7710 session.cc:3633] Update Frame Delay to
3 frames. W/native  ( 7710): W0000 00:00:1731942793.122889    7710
view_manager_utils.cc:133] Display geometry has an invalid width: 0
I/native  ( 7710): I0000 00:00:1731942793.139967    7710
camera_config_manager.cc:719] UpdateBugFixes on CameraConfigManager is
unimplemented! I/native  ( 7710): I0000 00:00:1731942793.140107
7710 session.cc:1284] Entering Session::Resume. I/native  ( 7710):
I0000 00:00:1731942793.140165    7710 session.cc:1418]
Session::ResumeWithAnalytics returning OK. D/AndroidRuntime( 7710):
Shutting down VM E/AndroidRuntime( 7710): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 7710): Process: com.example.shopping_mall_app, PID:
7710 E/AndroidRuntime( 7710): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to
resume activity
{com.example.shopping_mall_app/com.example.shopping_mall_app.MainActivity}:
java.lang.NullPointerException: null cannot be cast to non-null type
android.view.View E/AndroidRuntime( 7710):    at
android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:5512)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7710):  at
android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:5593)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7710):  at
android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem.execute(ResumeActivityItem.java:57)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7710):  at
android.app.servertransaction.ActivityTransactionItem.execute(ActivityTransactionItem.java:45)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7710):  at
android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:180)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7710):  at
android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:98)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7710):  at
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2693)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7710):  at
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) E/AndroidRuntime(
7710):    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:230)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7710):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:319)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7710):  at
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:9063)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7710):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native
Method) E/AndroidRuntime( 7710):  at
com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:588)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7710):  at
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1103)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7710): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException:
null cannot be cast to non-null type android.view.View
E/AndroidRuntime( 7710):  at
com.difrancescogianmarco.arcore_flutter_plugin.BaseArCoreView.getView(BaseArCoreView.kt:88)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7710):  at
io.flutter.plugin.platform.VirtualDisplayController.getView(VirtualDisplayController.java:278)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7710):  at
io.flutter.plugin.platform.VirtualDisplayController.resetSurface(VirtualDisplayController.java:294)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7710):  at
io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformViewsController.onResume(PlatformViewsController.java:1090)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7710):  at
io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.onPostResume(FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.java:587)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7710):  at
io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity.onPostResume(FlutterActivity.java:833)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7710):  at
android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:9199)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7710):  at
android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:5484)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7710):  ... 13 more I/BLASTBufferQueue( 7710):
SurfaceView[]@0#8 onFrameAvailable the first frame is
available W/native  ( 7710): W0000 00:00:1731942793.189536    8666
motion_analysis_calculator.cc:830] Requested image format in
RegionFlowComputation does not match video stream format. Overriding.
I/native  ( 7710): I0000 00:00:1731942793.189862    8666
region_flow_computation.cc:621] Instantiating and using NEON optimized
non-OpenCV KLT. I/Process ( 7710): Sending signal. PID: 7710 SIG: 9


You need to copy the text of the specific exception message you encountered and provide it here.

@DevQt ive added the logs, sorry for not providing them earlier
